# How do I toggle between Debug and Release builds in Xcode 6 / 7 / 8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode7, xcode9, xcode10

How do I get Xcode to build an OS X app in release mode? I can only seem to find instructions for earlier versions and none of the screenshots match. I didn't see anything when I put "release" into the help menu's search.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

In Xcode 6 - 10:

Choose **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme**. Change the `Build Configuration` under the `Info` tab.

Shortcut: hold <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> and click the run button `▶`.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Man, never would have discovered that.

Comment: @drewish The product icon on the left top corner (on the right of "Run" and "Stop" button) also has a shortcut for "Edit Scheme".

Comment: After looking at the scheme, the other short cut to get a release build is to profile the app.

Comment: I don't see where the actual .app files end up.

Comment: You should use "archive" to get the actual .app.

Comment: It should be noted that 'Edit Scheme' allows one to edit the defaults for any of the predefined schemes (e.g. 'Run', 'Test', 'Profile', 'Archive', etc) so that they use the 'Release' or 'Debug' configurations.

Comment: This would have to be the most "hidden" thing in all of computing  :O

Comment: bounty paid to spectacular answer, @skyline75489  :)

Answer (score 15):

When you want to generate a release build, choose Product -> Archive. That is a Release build. Now you can export as a Mac OS X app.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way with a project that has the default set up for schemes is just to do Product -> Build For -> Profiling.

Comment: Nice. Then is there an easy way to run it, without the profiler also starting up?

Comment: I would like to know this too. I don't want the profiler to start up.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! If you want to run as well as build, use the other answer by skyline75489.

Comment: Profiling should have nothing to do with preparing a release version of the app.