# React Native iOS app different code on simulator vs ad hoc/App Store

Tags: ios, react-native

I have been working on a React Native app for several weeks.  I recently pushed a version to TestFlight.  When I started getting feedback from users I noticed that their screenshots were different than the latest changes I made.  They were from older revisions.

I ran the app in the iOS Simulator.  I get the correct version of the code.

I ran the app on a device connected to my Mac.  I get the correct version of the code.

I ran the app distributed ad hoc and I get an older version of the app.

I haven't seen anything like this before and baffled as to what could cause the problem.

Comment: Did you set your configuration to debug instead of release? One thing to make sure is, the adhoc build you created should have proper JS bundling. Whenever you archive your project via xCode, you shall see the metro bundler appear.

Comment: I have only been doing mobile development for a couple of months (and only because the previous developer didn't work out).  I'm not really familiar with Xcode's schemes.  I'm not sure how this would have changed.

Comment: Another post with the same problem.  I'll change the scheme settings and retry the ad hoc build. [RN Debug and Release Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478896/react-native-xcode-debug-and-release-scheme-two-different-builds)

Comment: Sure, let me know if that helps (:

Comment: @TommyLeong I'm still having problems.  I created a new ExpoKit project and built to simulator, to device and then ad hoc distribution.  Everything worked OK.  Still having issues with the original project that I asked about.  I see the updates in every build destination except for ad hoc.  It's still an older release.

Comment: Glad you tested with a new project, smart move. You can verify the configuration between this 2 projects, you should see some differences. Again, my advice will be check your `build configuration`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059697/how-do-i-toggle-between-debug-and-release-builds-in-xcode-6-7-8

Answer (score 0):

I connected with Brent Vatne on Expo's Slack.  I forgot to run `expo publish` before running the release build.